# Migrating from LAMP+AngularJS to something more mixed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, lamp

We have a web app (CRM type) working on Linux (Debian) with Apache, MariaDb and PHP for the backend, and AngularJS (1.x) for the frontend.

Thinking about a redesign, I need advices on a solution I have in mind, but I'm not sure it would be relevant...

---

A new website (e-commerce) will come along the CRM and use directly or not (API) the same database.

So my first take would be **to put the MariaDb on a dedicated VM**. It uses much ressource right now, so much more with another app using it.

Then the CRM and website could connect directly in remote (too risky?) or call **an API**. I guess the second solution would be better and means **I could put my backend PHP part** (already working as an API for AngularJS) along with the database, on that new VM.
I guess Debian + Nginx would be a good choice to go with them.
I prefere PHP to handle databases 'cause I'm used to it.

On the other hand I would still have AngularJS alone, a deprecated JS framework.

One thing that was hard to work with, about AngularJS/PHP, was that sometimes I needed to format data for Angular from PHP, and vice versa. **It wasn't very clear where to put that formating**, 'cause the backend was more about the database and not the frontend, and the frontend more about layout than PHP ORM ans design.

Furthermore, we'd like to keep the CRM as a SPA (Single Page Application).

My take on that would be to go on **a MEAN stack, without de M (MongoDB)**, starting from scratch, just keeping Debian and installing NodeJS, ExpressJS and Angular or another JS framework (Vue, React...).

A hole JS stack to have the same language and gain speed and performance with many little transactions with the server (assets, calls and promises to retrieve data from database). Also to learn more on JS and NodeJS particularly.

- **NodeJS** to create the environnement and a web server, in place of Apache.
- **Angular** (or another) to put data into HTML, and have the less treatments possible.
- **ExpressJS** to be that intermediate part I was talking to, the place where formating can be performed: retrieving data from the views, formating them, sending them to the API, handling the response, formating it if necessary and returning it to the view.

It means I would go from one VM with:

```
AngularJS (frontend) -> PHP framework (backend) -> Database
```

To two VM with:

```
Angular (app frontend) -> Express (app backend) -> PHP API (database backend) -> Database.
```

What do you think of my use-case and the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are several benefits to splitting up your services, but almost equally many different solutions, so you need to ask yourself what your goal is. Performance? High availability/failover? You might need a lot of VMs, geo-redundancy, load-balanced VIPs, etc.

You can also look into making containerized services with Docker.

You talk about moving the database onto a separate VM, but that it might be risky. Why? If they are both on an isolated network, it should not be an issue.

If you're looking for stack advice, since you're talking about a full remake, I would recommend something both stable and modern like Laravel + VueJS for the web/API part. You're already comfortable with PHP, and a setup with Nginx will probably be much faster. But of course, there are almost infinite combinations to choose from these days.

As for the "direct or not" DB access: Having a versioned API is always a benefit.

Serving the SPA frontend will require very few resources, so your bottleneck will be between the API backend and DB. You can make it scalable by putting the API behind a VIP and load balance with something like HAProxy/Nginx.

Comment: Goals to reach: "secure" database behind a webservice, cause now we have one app, but tomorrow there will be 2 app using the same database. Give the database/webservice dedicated ressources, not to penalize the use of the CRM. Give the CRM, the website and the webservice/database dedicated VM to be independant.

Comment: Concerning the stack, I was only talking about the CRM and webservice. We will work on the website with a partner that will make propositions for its stack.

Right now my take on the CRM would be VueJS more that Angular, cause I'll have a complete frawework (ExpressJs) on the backend, so I plan to pick a light framework or library for the views, dedicating data treatments to ExpressJS.

Comment: But what that new stack means, is that I will have to deal with 3 routing procedures, one for each part of the stack: VueJS (routes for the browser) / ExpressJS (routes for VueJS) / Webservice (routes for ExpressJS and the website to come).
I wonder if it's a "good" operating stack.

Comment: Concerning "risks" about the database access, I was refering to a direct connection to the database from remotes apps (not going through a webservice). Even if these web apps are not hacked, they could do wrong and make much damage on data stored.